# ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.6 con "pip" al intentar vincular proyecto Python a Vercel

Tags: python

Tengo problemas con el "pip" para vincular mi proyecto Python a Vercel. Tengo la versión 3.10 de Py.

> Error! Command failed: python3.6 /tmp/1960d256/get-pip.py --user
> ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.6 The minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py instead.

Instalé la versión 3.7 de Python y sigue saliendo lo mismo.

Comment: hola que tal, podrias asegurarte de estar usando el interprete de python 3.7 o una version superior como 3.9, para no tener problemas futuros

Comment: ¿Qué te devuelve `python --version`?